# List of forms in django

Tags: django

i'm trying to create a list of items that belong to a specific contract of a user in django. In this list, the user must be able to acces a form with all the items that belong to this specific contract, and edit their value.

I've tried to use formsets, but the Items are not related to the contract, despite of a M2M field in the contract itself, so the error that i've been facing is:

`'contract_generator.Item' has no ForeignKey to 'contract_generator.ClientContract'`.

The are the **models** that are in use:

```
    class ClientContract(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        original_contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        contract_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    
        # Value related information
        total_value = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
        installments = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
        # Items and clausules of the contract
        items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True, null=True)
        clausules = models.ManyToManyField(Clausule, blank=True, null=True)
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.contract_name

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=90)

    item_value = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12)
    item_qt = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12)
    item_total = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12)

    # Unity options
    METERS = 'MT'
    LITERS = 'LT'
    UNITY_CHOICES = [
        (METERS, 'Meters'),
        (LITERS, 'Liters'),
    ]

    unity = models.CharField(choices=UNITY_CHOICES, default=METERS, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

This is the **view** that i've built using **formset**:

```
@login_required
def adjust_values(request, id):
    ItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ClientContract, Item, fields=('item_value', 'item_qt', 'item_total'))
    contract = get_object_or_404(ClientContract.objects.filter(user=request.user), pk=id)
    formset = ItemFormSet(instance=contract)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset.ItemForm(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'formset': formset}
    return render(request, 'item_formset.html', context)
```

Is it possible to maybe create a loop to iterate between the forms, of the items that are linked in this specific contract?